# For $P=(a,b), P'=(a', b')$, there is a unique circle for which $P, P'$ are the ends of its diameter, and having the equation displayed below.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $P=(a,b), P'=(a',b')$ be distinct points. Show that there is a unique circle for which $P, P'$ are the ends of its diameter, and having the equation displayed below. For fixed $P$, describe the locus of points $P'$ for which the circle passes through the origin

$$(x-a)(x-a')+(y-b)(y-b')=0$$

I knew that the center of the circle passing through the points $P, P'$ was $(\frac{a+a'}{2}, \frac{b+b'}{2})$. But I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: This is obviously an exercise. You will have to describe first in details what you have tried to do.

Comment: I think the third sentence is at the heart of this problem. But I don't understand what the third sentence means. What does the third sentence say?

Comment: It means that now $P=(a,b)$ is fixed while $P'$ varies (that is, $a'$ and $b'$ are parameters). We wish to find the points $P'$ for which the corresponding circle passes through $(0,0)$.

Comment: @곤뇽이조아 The next step is to find the radius of the circle and then use the expression of a circle to get the formula given in the question. A circle centered around the point $(x_0,y_0)$ of radius $r$ is described by the expression $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$. Then use the expressions for the center and the radius to obtain the result. Finally, you need to find all the points $P'$ for which the circle passes through zero, that is, the point $(0,0)$ belongs to the circle.